# Abstracting .NET Core 3 Application Startup Issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create a common start up process for all of my ASP.NET Core 3 projects, and so want to abstract out a working start up routine out to a class library for re-use.

I've therefore created a .NET Core 3.1 Class Library, and added all the references that are needed for it to compile and potentially run:

```
using Amazon.CertificateManager;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NetCore3ApplicationBase;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UtilityCore;
```

(UtilityCore being an in-house library)

I added a 'startup class':

```
namespace NetCoreApplicationBase
{
    public static class ProgramBase
    {
         public static void ApplicationStartup(string[] args)
         {
             CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
         }
    }
}
```

...and modified a sample .NET Core application to call the ApplicationStartup method in Program.cs:Main.

However, when the CreateHostBuilder line is called, I get the exception:

```
The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection
```

But this error ONLY occurs if the CreatHostBuilder code is abstracted out to another library.  If this code is embedded in the application, it works perfectly.

From some digging around this error is most commonly associated with EFCore and that suggests that on start up the application (via aspnetcore.Hosting) is searching for an appropriate DataContext to use.

But providing that in the HostBuilder using the:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

...makes no difference.

*** UPDATE 1 ***

The CreatHostBuilderMethod looks like this:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>           

        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<MyServiceName>();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseContentRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); 
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                
        });
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Modifying the CreateHostBuilder method to only accept the services, results in the same error message.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>           



        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

        .UseWindowsService().ConfigureServices((services) =>

        {

            services.AddHostedService<MyServiceName>();

        })

        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>

        {

            webBuilder.UseContentRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); 

            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                

        });
```

Can anyone shed any light on why there is this discrepancy in start up behaviour please?

Comment: How does `CreateHostBuilder` method look like?

Comment: I've added the method to the post as Update 1

Comment: The error message seems to describe the problem:
The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection.
You pass an action as parameter to the method.

Comment: Whilst I agree you'd think that, it doesn't explain why the Hosting Extension approach works when the code is not abstracted out.  Moreover, even if you modify the ConfigureServices call just to accept the Services collection, the same error occurs.

Comment: Probably some code optimization.
Your update 2 does not pass an IServiceCollection but an Action<IServiceCollection> this is something different.

Comment: Good point.  Let's see if that makes a difference

Comment: So, the ConfigureServices method ONLY accepts an IAction<IServiceCollection> or IAction<HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection> which is coming from Extension.Hosting.  Perhaps I'm missing another reference?

Comment: Taking the ConfigureServices call out completely results in the same error too!

Comment: Thank you!  I worked out what's wrong.  The culprit was the UseStartup<> call.  I'd added additional parameters to the function call in the start up implementation, which meant it no longer mirrored the delegate that was expected!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointers in the comments, I worked out what was wrong.

```
  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

was pointing to a class, where I'd modified the ConfigureServices parameters and added some extra ones, meaning it no longer matched the delegate the application start up was expecting.

D'oh!